# Multiply two value in a file and get output in number format means after decimal value it should not give 0

Tags: unix, awk

I want to check column 13 and and column 15 and if both are equal the it should return "True"

Output 
0.015 ABC 87 1558 1 1 4-30-16 4-30-16 917303625135 9141079167560945 1558 103.0000 1.545 1.71667 1.5450

Command used
awk -F" " '{ if($6==1) {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$12*$1,$12/60,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20} else {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$12*$1,$12/60,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20}}' | head -1

I am getting 1.5450 that's the reason I am getting "False".

Comment: Try adding zero to each number

Comment: Before you keep asking more poor-quality questions, please read [ask]

Comment: agreed with @glenn jackman

Comment: @glenn It's not a poor question if u need more info then u can ask but it's not a poor question

Comment: I cannot disagree more. The responsibility is on you. Read [ask].

Comment: If the solution is not possible then pls tell it's not feasible.... I know the t&c of how to ask

Comment: Anurag your questions are terrible which is why they keep getting downvoted and your reputation is still 1 after asking 5 questions. Follow @glennjackman's advice and the advice you've been getting from others and learn [ask] a question.

Comment: @EdMorton The question which I asked as per you it's terrible but I am new in awk and wherever I stuck I asked question. Don't say that my questions are terrible or poor etc. And if I have to read how to ask there should a point also how to reply ...

Comment: No-one is criticizing you for the things you are asking about, we are telling you that the **way** you ask the questions is what is causing [every question you ask](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6348686/anurag) to get downvoted and/or closed, why you are getting very few answers to most of your questions and why your reputation is not increasing. It is not a subjective judgement on our part - there are guidelines for asking questions (again, see [ask]) which you are clearly ignoring (where's your [mcve]?) and you are clearly experiencing the negative consequences of doing so.

Comment: Thanks ... I read how to ask ....

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```
for num in 1.5850 15.8900 1.585000 2.034; do
   printf "Input: %10s ==> " "${num}"
   sed 's/[0]*$//' <<< "${num}"
done
```

Result:

```
Input:     1.5850 ==> 1.585
Input:    15.8900 ==> 15.89
Input:   1.585000 ==> 1.585
Input:      2.034 ==> 2.034
```

The question becomes more complicated, when you mant to keep significant zeroes like in `10`. I extended the testcases and the solution:

```
for num in 1.5850 15.8900 1.585000 2.034 30 12.0; do
   printf "Input: %10s ==> " "${num}"
   sed 's/\(\.[0-9]*[1-9]\)[0]*$/\1/; s/\.0$//' <<< "${num}"
done
```

which gives

```
Input:     1.5850 ==> 1.585
Input:    15.8900 ==> 15.89
Input:   1.585000 ==> 1.585
Input:      2.034 ==> 2.034
Input:         30 ==> 30
Input:       12.0 ==> 12
```

Comment: Thanks Walter.. I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: I want to remove zero from 16th column and then print all the record. I use 
sed 's/\(\.[0-9]*[1-9]\)[0]*/\1/' but it is not working. Pls help

Comment: I do not understand. 16th column? Do you have a string? Is this a new question> Did you have the same output that I had? For what value of num do you have a problem ?